# launch orientation of iPad is incorrect for landscape orientation (upside down)

Tags: iphone

I read a few different posts on the orientation on launch, but I'm still unsure how it works.  We are only supporting landscape orientation.  In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I do:

```
    HomeController *myHome = [[HomeController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeController" bundle:nil];
    myHome.navigationItem.title = @"Your Dashboard";
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myHome];
    [myHome release];

    self.navigationController = navController;
    [navController release];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

In my HomeController class:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);    
}
```

When I start the app however on the device, it can start upside down.  How do I avoid that from happening?  I saw some posts on people detecting for the status bar orientation in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  If I do this after the `self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;` code:

```
NSLog(@"%i", [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
```

I always get 3.  From there, I'm not sure what I can do to fix the upside down issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the supported orientations in your Info.plist.  See the `Supported interface configurations` and `Supported interface configurations (iPad)` in your Info.plist.