# Force UIViewController orientation

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I did some research but cannot seem to find the answer to have my rootViewController of my navigationController be correct on start up.  My original question was here: [launch orientation of iPad is incorrect for landscape orientation (upside down)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776002/launch-orientation-of-ipad-is-incorrect-for-landscape-orientation-upside-down).

In my info.plist, I have it set to support both landscape orientations.  If I change my rootViewController to be:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
//    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation); // original that does not work
    return YES;
}
```

then my app starts in the right orientation.  However, I do not want to support portrait modes.  I only want to support landscape modes.  I thought I could force the orientation and prevent it from switching to portrait modes by doing something like this:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = orientation;
    }
    else {

    }
```

But this does not prevent the app from being rotated to portrait mode.  Is it possible to force the orientation?  Is there something else I need to do in order for the startup orientation to be correct (landscape mode only)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just created a sample project, set my Supported interface orientations (iPad) to Landscape Left and Landscape Right (in info.plist).

I then used:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation); 
}
```

and it works fine. It's forced to landscape not matter how i rotate it.

Do you have any other view controllers visible that might be returning YES to all orientations? This could confuse it.

Comment: Because I use a UINavigationController in my AppDelegate, is that a problem at all?

Comment: It's not a problem as long as all the other view controllers that you use in the UINavigationController have the same shouldAutorotate policy.

Comment: Hmm, I am still getting a problem. When my app first launches, I have to show a modal form and a UIAlertView per the requirements.  Basically like this, where tvc is my viewController I show modally: `        tvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        tvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:tvc animated:YES];`.  This ViewController has its shouldAutoRotate also set to return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation).  Could this view controller cause it to start up incorrect?